# Repair C compiler via telnet

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, perl, c, cpanel

When I try to install a perl mod in cPanel I get this error:

> Checking C compiler....Could not locate an executable "gcc" binary....Done ** Unrecoverable Error ** The C compiler is not functional and auto repair failed. Perl module installs require a working C compiler. Please repair the C compiler and try again.

Is there a way to fix, repair or reinstal the C Compiler with Telnet?

Comment: … but why `telnet`? Is that the only way you can connect. That's terribly insecure.

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: Use [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CPanel does not seem to allow access to compilers, since `gcc` is not found.

See [the documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Compiler+Access):

> When compiler access is enabled (default), the /usr/bin/gcc file has the following permissions:
>
> ```
> -rwxr-xr-x    root    root
> ```
>
> When you disable compiler access, cPanel changes the permissions of the /usr/bin/gcc file to:
>
> ```
> -rwxr-x---    root    compiler
> ```
>
> The compiler group contains the cpanel user and any users that you add to the Allow specific users to use the compilers menu.

This means that apparently your user cannot run a compiler, and therefore not compile any Perl modules.